# Adjusting dates in a SQL Server table to avoid overlapping coverage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with patient insurance coverage that we will call `tb_ins`. An example of one patient is listed below. I need to show coverage without overlapping dates with ins_type 4 taking priority. Meaning if a patient has ins_type 3 from 01/01/2019 - 06/01/2019 and ins_type 4 from 02/01/2019-10/01/2019 I want to return ins_type 3 from 01/01/2019 -01/31/2019 and type 4 from 02/01/2019- 12/01/2019.

Example #1 tb_ins:

[image]

Returns:

[image]

Example #2 tb_ins:

[image]

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Does your model have a system calendar or junk dimension? That would make your life a lot easier. Otherwise I'd recursively create the date sequences and get the set  differences.

Comment: How many different types of insurance are there?  What the the precedence rules for the additional types?

Comment: Just two insurance types 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is foolproof, but in theory you could do this by separating it into a bunch of criteria and UNION the results:

```
select x.*
from
(

--When period of type 4 is completely within the type 3 period (First part)

select a.Pat_ID,a.Ins_Type,a.Eff_date,DATEADD(d,-1,b.Eff_date) as End_date
from #tb_ins a
inner join #tb_ins b
on b.Eff_date between a.Eff_date and a.End_date and b.Ins_type=4 and a.Ins_type=3 and a.Pat_id=b.Pat_id

UNION ALL

--When period of type 4 is completely within the type 3 period (Second part)

select a.Pat_ID,a.Ins_Type,DATEADD(d,1,b.End_date) as Eff_date,a.End_date
from #tb_ins a
inner join #tb_ins b
on b.Eff_date between a.Eff_date and a.End_date and b.Ins_type=4 and a.Ins_type=3 and b.End_date<a.End_date and a.Pat_id=b.Pat_id

UNION ALL

--When start of type 3 period is within type 4 period, but the end is past the type 4 end

select a.Pat_ID,a.Ins_Type,DATEADD(d,1,b.End_date) as Eff_date,a.End_date
from #tb_ins a
inner join #tb_ins b
on a.Eff_date between b.Eff_date and b.End_date and b.Ins_type=4 and a.Ins_type=3 and b.End_date<a.End_date and a.Pat_id=b.Pat_id

UNION ALL

--When type 3 has no overlap with type 4

select a.*
from #tb_ins a
inner join #tb_ins b
on a.Eff_date not between b.Eff_date and b.End_date and b.Eff_date not between a.Eff_date and a.End_date and a.Pat_id=b.Pat_id and a.Ins_Type=3

UNION ALL

--All type 4

select * 
from #tb_ins where Ins_type=4
)x
Order by x.Pat_ID,x.Eff_date
```

I checked it for the two sample cases you had shared and it works there. Hope this at least gets you started.